# Get .net drop down to keep selected value after page load

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have been working a program for a year now on and off and i am still having an issue with a day one problem. I have a dropdownlist that is populated from a SQL datasource. what i want to happen is that when an item is selected from the list use Response.Redirect to reload the same page because my app pulls query-string data to fill in other parts of the app. the problem is that after redirecting the dropdownlist shows the first item on the list and not the now currently select displayed item. 1 yr later and still having noob problems. i have googled it and have not been able to find a solution... any ideas

```
page 1
<div>


    <asp:DropDownList ID="ClientDD" runat="server" 
        AutoPostBack="True" 
        DataSourceID="ClientDDq" 
        DataTextField="CaseName"
        DataValueField="filetag"
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="ClientRD">  
    </asp:DropDownList>



    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="ClientDDq" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:craftConnectionString1 %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [CaseFiles]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>



</div>
```

page 1.cs

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{




    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        ClientDD.DataBind();
        ClientDD.Items.FindByValue(ClientDD.SelectedValue).Selected = true;
        ClientDD.SelectedItem.Selected = true;
    }


}


protected void ClientRD(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("sonic.aspx?foil=" + ClientDD.SelectedItem.Value, true);


}
```

}

everything works as it should but the dropdown resets. Any new ideas/samples would be of great help

Updated version thanks to David

page 2

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        ClientDD.DataBind();

        var selectedValue = Request.QueryString["foil"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedValue))
            ClientDD.Items.FindByValue(selectedValue).Selected = true;

    }


}

protected void ClientRD(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("sonic.aspx?foil=" + ClientDD.SelectedItem.Value, true);


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, why are you using `Response.Redirect` to reload the page?  The page will naturally load itself after processing the post-back.

Aside from that, there's no code in `Page_Load` to capture the query string value you're passing it in the redirect.  You'll need to capture that value and actually *set* the selected element.  Potentially something like this:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    ClientDD.DataBind();

    // really not sure what you're doing here.
    // if this isn't a post-back then there wouldn't *be* a selected value...
    ClientDD.Items.FindByValue(ClientDD.SelectedValue).Selected = true;
    ClientDD.SelectedItem.Selected = true;

    // select based on the query string
    var selectedValue = Request.QueryString["foil"];
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedValue))
        CliendDD.Items.FindByValue(selectedValue).Selected = true;
}
```

Comment: i use Response.Redirect to reload the page so that the url is changed to contain a number which when the page loads other objects on the page look for and run there own query from.

Comment: @user3266908: If those other objects are server-side elements then they can use the current selected value on `ClientDD` in the server-side code, referencing it just like the call to `Response.Redirect` references it.  Either way, if those objects need to respond to the query string, then setting the selected value also needs to happen in response to the query string.  The `DropDownList` in this case is an "object on the page" that needs to look for the query string value.

Comment: I have made the changes and it works. all the other objects on the page work as well. Im not sure if i am doing this the most effective way. have the controls look for something in the query string but using the session states is above me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using
`ClientDD.SelectedItem.Selected=true;`try setting the `ClientDD.SelectedIndex`
So something like this:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        ClientDD.DataBind();
        var index = ClientDD.Items.IndexOf(ClientDD.Items.FindByValue(ClientDD.SelectedValue));
        ClientDD.SelectedItem = index;


        // select based on the query string
        selectedValue = Request.QueryString["foil"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedValue))
            var index = ClientDD.Items.IndexOf(ClientDD.Items.CliendDD.Items.FindByValue(selectedValue));
        ClientDD.SelectedItem = index;

}
```